# Bitmap decodeFile returns null in Ice Cream Sandwitch

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I ran into this weird bug or something in android's 4.0.1 Ice Cream Sandwitch, where `Bitmap.decodeFile(String fileLocation);` returns null and returns `SKImageDecoder::Factory returned null` on Logcat. I dont know what is causing it, but it works perfect on android >= 2.3.7 gingerbread. I do not have a ICS device, so i am testing it on emulator, but if you have a device, could you test that out and tell me if you get the same error. Anyone know any alternatives to decodeFile? Oh, the image is stored in the internal cache directory of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you retrieving the image from the net and saving it? This error usually occurs when the file cannot be encoded into an image. Are you sure you're retrieving the correct file? Tried a different image?

I've got a ICS device (Galaxy Nexus), if you want to try it outside the emulator.

Comment: thanks i figured out that the way i was downloading the image from the internet was not correct which led to corrupted image. i fixed it now.